# How to turn off pin 23 correctly? SSH connection crashed

Tags: pi-3, gpio, ssh, led, output

I am a newbie to the Raspberry Pi and as the title says, I was connected to my RPi through SSH protocol and the session suddenly was terminated due to a 'FlowSocketReader' error or something.

My LED is currently on and I am questioning how to turn it off **properly**. I can't apply the `GPIO.cleanup()` command here because it assumes that I don't have any channels set up yet.

`GPIO(23, False)` doesn't work either..

Does someone have a tip for me?

Comment: Reboot your Pi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your SSH session is restored, otherwise reboot ...

On the standard terminal command line:

```
gpio -g mode 23 out
gpio -g write 23 0
```

From Python:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(23,0)
```

Comment: Thank u. can u kindly provide link to resources that contain more information about `gpio -g mode` and `gpio -g write` commands?